# Dropwizard - How to access javascript methods

Tags: javascript, dropwizard

In my resource java file, I want to call a javascript method from a js file that resides at `resources/assets/Helper.js`. I don't know how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
URL resource = Resources.getResource("assets/Helper.js");
String javascript = Resources.toString(resource, Charsets.UTF_8);
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript" /* "nashorn" if Java 8 */);
Object result = engine.eval(javascript);
```